# wordpress. html/css to theme..link to images?

Tags: wordpress, image

Im trying to create my own WP-theme from my html/css-site.
I managed to migrate the html/css but the images won´t show up.

I realise that i have to change the img src-path but do i also have to add som php?

What does the path look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are the images intended to be part of the theme?  If so, then I'd recommend making a directory called `images` or something similar (I've seen some people use `assets`) in the theme's root directory (ie, `wp-content/themes/[theme]/images`).

Then you should be able to access them using `get_template_directory_uri()`, like so:

```
<img src='<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/your-image.ext'>
```

If you're creating a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and want to allow overrides of the parent themes images, replace `get_template_directory_uri()` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

#### References

- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)
- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)
- [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: If you're just asking about general images in your site's pages and posts, then you're better off to upload them using [WordPress's Media](http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages) system.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Dunno why but this didnt work for me..Tried both suggestions but no images were added. A weird thing is this: If a add an image in my Css.file as a background-image(url): (image.ext) it works but not my img src files...

Comment: Just to clarify: when I said `image.ext` in my code, I meant that as a placeholder for your image names (`abc.gif`, `lmnop.jpg`, `xyz.png`, and so forth.)

Comment: Yes I got that =)
I should probably read up a bit more on Php etc..before i continue. But thank you!